# How to subscribe multiple topic using @KafkaListner annotation

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka message broker to publish and subscribe event. For that using spring infrastructure. My requirement is I need to create one consumer which will subscribe multiple topic.

Following is the code which is working perfectly fine when it subscribe to single topic.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "com.customer.nike")
  public void receive(String payload) {
    LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", payload);
  }
```

But I want , it should be subscribe to some pattern of topic. 
like..

```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "com.cusotmer.*.nike")
      public void receive(String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", payload);
      }
```

In this code * will keep changing. It may be some numeric value like 1000. 1010 and so on. For this I also used SpeL.

```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "#{com.cusotmer.*.nike}")
      public void receive(String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", payload);
      }
```

But this one is also not working for me. 
Could someone help me to subscribe multiple topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your last snippet of code have typo "cusotmer" instead of "customer", maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `topicPattern` instead of `topics`?

Comment: Hi @AlexandreJuma,

Thanks for reply, I changed it from topics to topicPattern and now its working fine. 
but now one more thing , I also want to get the topic string inside '@KafkaListener' method. So what I can actually from which topic event is coming. 
Could you please suggest what I can do for this?

Comment: Hey @still-learning, pleasse check my response below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the **subscription of multuiple topics**, you can use [topicPatterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#topicPattern--) to achieve that:

> The topic pattern for this listener. The entries can be 'topic
> pattern', a 'property-placeholder key' or an 'expression'. The
> framework will create a container that subscribes to all topics
> matching the specified pattern to get dynamically assigned partitions.
> The pattern matching will be performed periodically against topics
> existing at the time of check. An expression must be resolved to the
> topic pattern (String or Pattern result types are supported).
>
> Mutually exclusive with topics() and topicPartitions().

```
@KafkaListener(topicPattern = "com.customer.*")
  public void receive(String payload) {
    LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", payload);
  }
```

Regarding the programatic access to **the topic name**, you can use `@Header` annotated method to extract a specific header value, defined by [KafkaHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/KafkaHeaders.html#RECEIVED_TOPIC), which in your case is [RECEIVED_TOPIC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/KafkaHeaders.html#RECEIVED_TOPIC):

> The header containing the topic from which the message was received.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "com.customer.nike")
    public void receive(String payload, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", payload);
    LOG.info("received from topic: {}", topic);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topics}'.split(',')}"` where `kafka.topics` is taken from my property file and contains the comma separated topics to which my listener should listen to.

But may be, during start up u can add a logic to generate all the possible topics and assign to a variable, which can be later used as above.

Update : Wild card is possible as Alexandre commented below.

Comment: You can use wildcards. You can look it up here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#topicPattern--

Answer (score 1):

If we have to fetch multiple topics from the `application.properties` file :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = { "${spring.kafka.topic1}", "${spring.kafka.topic2}" })
```